# Which is correct REPL or command-line?

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, irb, method-missing

when i write method missing in Object class i'm getting the output different in each interface.

the code is

```
class Object
  def method_missing(hgh)
    puts self
  end
end
```

when i use REPL like irb, i get

[image]

when i use the command line, i get no error, any reasons would be helpful, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The **tl;dr** answer is that both are correct. Just more stuff happen in the REPL.

---

When you run the code from the command line like:

```
ruby script.rb
```

All that happens is that it's **e**valuated.

Whereas REPLs like IRB **r**ead your input, **e**valuate it and **p**rint it in a **l**oop.

In this case **e**valuating your code literally broke the REPL and resulted in the subsequent **p**rint failing.

---

Now you may be a bit confused by this. "There is a print in both cases, I use `puts`!". The print I'm referring to here is the result that gets visualised after each **e**valuation. In this case the method definition result (`=> :method_missing`).

---

It might not only be the **p**rinting itself. It can be the ton of other under the hood code that the REPL has to execute to keep state like *"what code was defined on which line"* and so on.

Think of what you just did - you made it so that **every** object has **every** method possible to return `nil`. That is not just for the code you write **in** the REPL. It's for the code **of** the REPL itself as well.

Comment: This. The REPL is a complex piece of Ruby code, and the OP just modified fundamentally how every single object in the system behaves. It would be very surprising if this *didn't* break something.

Comment: @ndnenkov In this scenario, what is the problem with writing "method_missing" method over there. If that was any other new method, it would not throw any error. Can i know why is this code behaving ODD!

Comment: @RamireddySamar `method_missing` is a special method in Ruby that gets invoked if you try to invoke a method on an object that doesn't exist. Ex. `4.foo` will invoke `4.method_missing :foo` as `4` doesn't have a `foo` method. So in a sense you just made it so `4` has `foo` (and any other method for that matter). That's what is so special about `method_missing` as opposed to other method names.

Comment: @ndnenkov It seems like, only when i have any code inside method_missing i.e. `puts self` , i get this error, if it contains nothing like 
`method_missing(met) do
end` 
then i'm not getting any error, what about this?

Comment: @RamireddySamar can you try this: `def method_missing(hgh); puts self; super; end` instead of your current implementation? (Aka just add a `super` at the end).

Comment: yes, but if that logic is calling super, then it should print the output(self) in console for every method call right? if yes, y am i not getting any output?. if no, why?